# how to build a toggle mapping for double click in vim

Tags: vim

I have following mapping in my .vimrc to handle double click on word to jump to next occurrence, now I just want the next double click to jump back to start

```
nnoremap <2-LeftMouse> *
```

I double click on a word and it jumps, I then use # to go back, however it would be nice if I could just double click again -- to toggle the jump - is the possible ???

so far I have solved it using RightMouse button to use # to go back - but it is not really a good solution

strange thing is that if I use * on a word in vim and then again use * on that word, if no more words it toggles around, however this is not happening when mapping it to mouse click

Comment: It sounds like you want to set a state variable on the first click, and change the behavior on the second click based on the state variable, followed by clearing the state variable.

Comment: yes but actually the default behavior of * would be ok

Comment: It seems to work correctly for me. I created a simple file with two instances of the phrase `Foobar` on different lines. Double-clicking the first one jumped to the second, and double-clicking the second returned to the first. Please show an example file where this breaks.

Comment: yes I guess my file contains more lines of different values - so its behavior is strange - however I want it to go backwards when double click again

Comment: it seems that double click sometimes fetch strange value - so perhaps that is why I am having issues

Comment: why not just pressing `*/#` `n/N` to navigate or jump? It would be much faster than  double click, left/ right, triple click... right?

Comment: You need to set the `mouse` option to normal mode so it can have effect. After that wherever you click the mouse will be set to that position and after mapping it to `*` it will search for the current word the cursor will move to the searched word. The problem now is when you press the next click with the mouse it will change the position of the mouse again which cause problems and the word where the cursor is, is the one which will be searched. So I suggest that you change the mapping because mouse click is not a good idea.